# Converting IN to EXISTS for counting users who have taken multiple kinds of actions

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, exists

I have a table full of users, timestamps, and different types of actions. Let's call them type A, B, and C:

```
| User ID   | Date      | ActionType |
--------------------------------------
| 1         | 10/2/14   | A          |
| 2         | 10/12/14  | A          |
| 3         | 11/1/14   | B          |
| 1         | 11/15/14  | B          |
| 2         | 12/2/14   | C          |
```

I'm trying to get counts of the number of users who have taken combinations of different action types within a time period -- for example, the number of users who have done both action A and action B between October and December.

This code works (for one combination of actions at a time), but takes forever to run:

```
SELECT
COUNT(DISTINCT `cm0`.`User ID`) AS `Users`

FROM `mytable` AS `cm0`
WHERE 
(`cm0`.`User ID` IN (SELECT `cm1`.`User ID` FROM `mytable` AS `cm1` WHERE
(`cm1`.`ActionType` = 'A' AND (`cm1`.`Date` BETWEEN dateA AND
dateB))) 
AND (`cm0`.`ActionType` = 'B') 
AND (`cm0`.`Date` BETWEEN dateA AND dateB))
```

I researched ways to do this using common table expressions, and then realized I couldn't do those in mySQL. Now I'm trying to figure out how to optimize with EXISTS instead of IN, but I'm having trouble fitting examples into what I need. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT cm0.User_ID) AS Users 
FROM mytable AS cm0
WHERE cm0.ActionType IN ('A', 'B') AND cm0.Date BETWEEN dateA AND dateB
GROUP BY cm0.User_ID 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT cm0.ActionType) = 2;
```

The above query will return **the number of users who have done both action A and action B between October and December**, but if you still want to use `EXISTS` then check below query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT cm0.User_ID) AS Users
FROM mytable AS cm0
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mytable AS cm1 
              WHERE cm0.User_ID = cm1.User_ID AND cm1.ActionType = 'A' AND cm1.Date BETWEEN dateA AND dateB
             ) AND cm0.ActionType = 'B' AND cm0.Date BETWEEN dateA AND dateB
```